# Android: File IO from SD card using the NDK

Tags: java, android, c, file-io, android-ndk

I am trying to write onto an output file using the NDK, and it doesn't seem to be working. The code I wrote looks like this:

```
JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_com_example_sdcardtest2_CppMethods_nativeCalculations (JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz, jdouble dub){
    jdouble hub = dub + 10;
    FILE* file = fopen("/sdcard/textTest.txt","w+");
    fputs("HELLO WORLD!\n", file);
    fclose(file);
return hub;
}
```

The reason why the return type is a double, is that I am planning on using the function for another purpose, but I'm trying out file io first. In the logcat, I am getting the following error:

```
Fatal signal 11: (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000c (code = 1) .....
```

Funny thing is, when I try to write to or read from the same file in the caller activity using java file io, I am not having any problems. And I made sure that I have write permissions in the manifest file. Also, if I remove the `FILE* file ...` line, and try to use the returned double value from the function, the program runs fine. Can someone please help? Could the problem be something I should include in the Android.mk or Application.mk files, for example?

**UPDATE**
I'm using a Samsung galaxy note 2, if that makes any difference

**UPDATE2**

Here's the full code:

java activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private TextView text1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    double d = CppMethods.nativeCalculations(2.80);
    String s = "The value of d is = " + d;

    File f1 = new File("/sdcard/textTest.txt");
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
         is = new FileInputStream(f1);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(is);


    this.text1.setText(reader.nextLine().subSequence(0, s.length()));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Here's the native method:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include "com_example_sdcardtest2_CppMethods.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


/*
 * Class:     com_example_sdcardtest2_CppMethods
 * Method:    nativeCalculations
 * Signature: (D)D
 */

JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_com_example_sdcardtest2_CppMethods_nativeCalculations
  (JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz, jdouble dub){
    jdouble hub = dub + 10;
    FILE* file = fopen("/sdcard/textTest.txt","w+");
    fputs("hello, world\n", file);
    fclose(file);




    return hub;
}
```

Here's Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_example_sdcardtest2_CppMethods.c
LOCAL_MODULE := com_example_sdcardtest2_CppMethods
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And here's the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sdcardtest2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.sdcardtest2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**UPDATE**

Last update: I tried the same code on someone else's phone, also a galaxy note 2, and it worked. It seems as though the problem was with my phone. *sigh*

Comment: The file is null indeed, but how does that make sense? If the file isn't in the directory, fopen would create it and then write onto it. Also, as I said in the question, using the same exact path in the Main.java activity file doesn't give me any error (using `File f1 = new File("/sdcard/textTest.txt")`

Comment: Do you have `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission?

Comment: here's the line from the manifest file: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>`.

Comment: and that's directly under `<manifest>` and you don't do anything funky in your code and sdcard is actually mounted and you are really really passing the same path in Java level?

Comment: I uploaded the whole code, and I also tried the path `/sdcard/external_sd/textTest.txt` and that didn't work as well, (I am using a samsung galaxy note 2)

Comment: are you reading or writing? why in native you open it for `r` and try to write to it? that's different from your first posting.

Comment: Oh my bad, I was trying stuff between the first post and copying the whole code, I just fixed it above.

Comment: What is wierd for me is that in all other answers on this site, it was sufficient to just open /sdcard/filename and that was it, but unfortunately that is not the case for me here.

Comment: If the code works from Java, why are you trying to do this in native code?  The bottleneck will almost certainly be the hardware and that won't be faster whether you use Java or C.

Comment: I am writing an application that runs an optimization using the data points read. It is much faster to run the optimization in C, as I have seen from the desktop application equivalent I wrote. In Java, it would take about 40 minutes, and just under 10 minutes in C. Wouldn't the performance comparison be equivalent on the phone? If I read the data in Java, my options are either optimize in Java, which I've seen to be much slower, or pass the data through to the native functions, which is obviously a bad idea.

Comment: Anyway, that's not the issue here, it's that everyone on this website who asked a similar question was happy with the answer `/sdcard/file_name.ext` as the path for fopen, but I'm the only one with whose getting a null pointer returned from it, and my only lead is that the product line of my phone (samsung galaxy) has a somehow different behaviour than other phones.

Comment: user1023420, can you install some low-level file browser to the phone and check top folder `/` for `sdcard`? Or ever run `ls -l /` in the terminal, both on your phone and on other phone.

Comment: Why are you doing two seemingly unrelated tasks in one function?

Comment: Hello, I am having the exact problem. How did you solve it?

Comment: We have exactly the same problem on variety on Samsung (and only Samsung) devices: S5, S4 and Note 4 (all running under Lollipop)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe file path is wrong. I used SDcard path as "/mnt/sdcard/".

I can't remember exactly, but you can try "/mnt/sdcard/..." or "mnt/sdcard/...".

Or, you can get the SDCard path using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()`.

Comment: please see the update above, it seems like it was a glitch with my phone :/

Comment: "or get the sdcard path using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()" Nope, and here's why: (too bad they closed this one) - user1023420 - it may not be your phone ... if you have "/storage/sdcard0" Samsung claims we have to append "/external_sd/" then the filename - but we have verified that it works differently on different S3 phones - fails on some, works inconsistently on others